# Dojo 1.9: placeAt automatically calls startup when parent widget has started up

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

[Dojo v1.9](http://dojotoolkit.org/)

I am writing some code that progrommatically creates a widget that I need to place into a layout widget. The problem I currently have is that `startup` is automatically called over aggressively by dojo.

If the layout widget has already started up, then `startup` is called when `placeAt(domNode)` is used. This is not desirable, it would be better to have to explicitly call `startup`.

I say this because with the current situation, `startup` is called twice, once for when `placeAt` is called and once for when `startup` is called manually straight after that by me.

The [Dojo docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#dijit-widgetbase) and [related tutorials](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/understanding_widgetbase/) say that when creating widgets programmatically you should always call `startup` manually to be sure correct parsing occurs. But the automatic calling of `startup` is causing some problems, with duplicate actions occuring on startup, I could move these into `postCreate`, but that is just hiding the problem.

Here is a simple example of the widget creation/startup...

```
var myWidget = new Widget();
myWidget.placeAt('mainContent');
myWidget.startup();
```

`mainContent` is a div within a ContentPane, here is the layout html...

```
<body class="claro">
    <div id="appLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
            <div id="mainContent"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Some text here</div>
        <div id="leftCol" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'left'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The code works, its really the issue of `startup` being called twice that I'm trying to resolve.

---

UPDATE: WORKAROUND

Suggested checks inside the `startup` function against the widget private variable `_started` are at least protecting me from duplication, here is an example of my check.

```
startup: function(){
    if (typeof this._started === "undefined"){
        // call inherited and pass on arguments
        this.inherited(arguments);

        // then do what ever you need here
    }
}
```

Notice I had to use `typeof` and not a `boolean` check, even though after `startup` the value  of `_started` is `true`. This was because I discovered the variable isn't actually declared until `startup` has run at least once, something to look out for.

Anyway, this offers me a workaround, but doesn't fix the issue of `startup` being called more than once by dojo.

Comment: see my update in answers. You can set _started to true after your startup code.

Comment: @Sean Zhao I believe that `_started` gets set to `true` or `false` after the first startup anyway, as long as `this.inherited` is called, or `startup` isn't overridden in your custom widget.

Answer (score 4):

`startup()` is called automatically quite often in Dojo. For example, whenever you call `addChild()` on a container widget, the child's `startup()` method is called. Looking at the source of `_WidgetBase`, `placeAt` is also one of those instance.

You should call `startup()` manually when you use something like `dom-construct` to place a dojo widget directly on a DOM node.

If you want to check if a widget has started already you can check the `_started` property inside the widget. This is set inside the `startup()` method.

Comment: I will probably have to add a check against `_started` I expect, but that is bad practice with it being marked as private.

Comment: You're right, I wouldn't use it lightly. If you wanted you could define your own started variable inside the widget, just set it to true in startup() and be sure to call this.inherited

Answer (score 2):

Automatically startup widget is a good feature, actually you don't need worry about startup being called twice if you follow the standard code for startup method like :

```
startup : function() {
    if (!this._started) {

        //your startup code at here

        this.inherited(arguments);
        this._started = true;

    }
},
```

Comment: Ah OK I see, do the check on `_started` internally to the widget, interesting. I'll try that.

Comment: By the way where did you find the 'standard code for startup' documentation that gives an example like yours above, it would be good to have a further reference?

Comment: @Jez , There are a lot of this kinds of use in dojo source code, for example, you can find in dijit/tests/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html or dijit/_WidgetBase.js

Comment: I can see why you are setting `_started` but I'm not sure if it is good practice to start setting private variables that are changed by a super class. Even if we know that the type will be boolean anyway, it is possible that a dojo update changes its type, thus possibly causing unexpected behaviour. I'd rely on the super declaring and defining `_started`, and then checking for that.